# Xcode Simulator builds: M1 vs Intel

Tags: swift, xcode, apple-m1, xcode13

Some in our team work on M1 Macs, others on Intel, and most of our CI infrastructure is still Intel-based. Building for release seems to be no issue, but I would like to set up a single project setting that builds for both Intel-based and M1-based Simulator.

So far the only way to make it work is either to add Excluded Architectures (Any iOS Simulator) - `arm64` is excluded on Intel, and `x86_64` is excluded on M1.

I want avoid having two different targets just for this and switching these settings back and forth is also not an option.

Questions:

- Is there a better way to set this up so that both Intel and M1 sims build successfully?
- How come I need this exclude setting anyway, given that "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to Yes? (also tried with No btw as some suggested - didn't help)

Comment: I also have the same issue with Xcode 13 and an SwiftUI app for iOS/watchOS. To make the SwiftUI preview work for watchOS targets, I have to exclude an architecture (arm64 or x86_64 depending on the build machine architecture).